# How to find precise cpu utilization at 1 sec granularity in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, cpu-usage

I want to get a decently accurate value for overall cpu utilization at 1 sec granularity,
while introducing minimal delay possible.

I tried "top" but that is not at all accurate because of the delay between cpu dumps.

Right now I am doing it by reading /proc/stat which works fine for 2 sec granularity, however I am not sure if it will work reliably at 1 sec granularity.
How frequent is /proc/stat updated ?

Also, any idea how accurate would it be read /proc/loadavg (or calling getloadavg()) would be ? Can it work reliably at 1 sec intervals ?

Any solution that can work on c/c++ should do.

Comment: could you use `clock_t times(struct tms *)` from `sys/times.h`?

Comment: Do you want the load average or the CPU/core utilization?

Comment: @nonchip That will only give you the elapsed CPU-*time* for the current process.

Answer (score 2):

Complex considerations aside, a single CPU is either active or not.

During a timespan, "CPU usage" is how much of that time was spent working, not how *hard* the work was.

The shorter the timespan you measure, the less the measurement makes sense. If you had a granularity of 1 nanosecond, you'd always find CPU usage at 100% or 0%.

2 seconds is a decent timespan. More, and you'd miss important spikes; less, and everything would be a spike.

Comment: Yes but the question is whether 1 seconds granularity is really that small still with faster hardware ? This was the reason I decided to go for 2 sec around 3-4 years ago... Since then cpus and kernel seems to be much more evolved.

Comment: I don't think faster hardware matters. Remember: CPU usage is not _how hard_, but _how frequent_. What matters is how often processes switch from blocking to actively computing -- process behaviour patterns, if you will. And that hasn't changed much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using top with the -d1 argument?

I use it often for testing and it sets the polling interval to 1sec (much faster than the default).

Per the man page for reference:

> ```
>   -d  :Delay-time interval as:  -d ss.t (secs.tenths)
>         Specifies the delay between screen updates, and overrides the
>         corresponding value in one's personal configuration  file  or
>         the  startup default.  Later this can be changed with the 'd'
>         or 's' interactive commands.
>
>         Fractional seconds are honored, but a negative number is  not
>         allowed.   In all cases, however, such changes are prohibited
>         if top is running in 'Secure mode', except for  root  (unless
>         the 's' command-line option was used).  For additional infor‐
>         mation on 'Secure mode' see topic  6a.  SYSTEM  Configuration
>         File.
> ```

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong but top is based cpu dumps right?  Is it reliably accurate ? I am looking for accuracy at least decently close to that of reading /proc/stat directly.